# Redux batch doesn't work properly on React Native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Need to call multiple dispatches. Trying to use batch from react-redux, but it triggers only the first dispatch inside the function. Tried to exchange dispatches, the same, triggers only the first one, checked in dev tools. Thunk is connected

In app:

```
  dispatch(
    setData({
      user,
      userLang,
      userToken,
      dateMargin,
    }),   )
```

Action:

```
export const setData = ({user, userLang, userToken, dateMargin}) => {
  return dispatch => {
    batch(() => {
      dispatch(setToken(userToken))
      dispatch(setLang(userLang))
      dispatch(setUser(user))
      dispatch(setDateMargin(dateMargin))
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `batch` is a re-export from `react-dom`. React-native does not have a similar API, so that is not possible there.

Generally, it is recommended to [Model Actions as Events, Not Setters](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#model-actions-as-events-not-setters), [Allow Many Reducers to Respond to the Same Action](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#allow-many-reducers-to-respond-to-the-same-action) and to [Avoid Dispatching Many Actions Sequentially](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#avoid-dispatching-many-actions-sequentially) (see the links for more explanation), so what you are doing here is pretty much an anti-pattern:
You have the logic in your component, although the big strentgh of Redux is that it moves the state logic out of your component, into your Store.

Going by the recommendations from the official Redux Style guide, you'd rather

```js
  dispatch(userLoggedIn({
    userToken,
    userLang,
    user,
    dateMargin
  })
```

and have potentially multiple reducers acting on that event-type action.